# Excluding Contacts from Householding in NPSP

Tags: npsp, households

### TL;DR

How do I use my own bucketing system for some Contacts and the NPSP Household Account system for others?

### The background

I have a pretty complex org to which I'd like to add the Nonprofit Starter Pack.  My development team is very excited by it, but I have a pretty mature product I support with the service side of the house and I don't want to cause undue ripples there.

On the service side, we're currently using a home-brewed auto-bucketing system for our individual Contacts.

### The Plan

I'd love to use the Household Account model for my Development team (and Contacts related to that) but I don't want to migrate my other teams' Contacts to the NPSP system just yet (though if I can get permissions straightened out, it makes sense to move there one day).

I'd like to exclude my client service contacts from Householding.  According to the documentation, you can only exclude RecordTypes from householding if you don't use the Household Account model, since this exclusion is just for the `Household__c` objects.

### The problem

So... I want to use the NPSP bucketing system for any Contacts on the Development side, and my bucketing system for all other Contacts.  Is the way to do this to add a `TDTM_Runnable` to call my bucketing system and add it into the TDTM workflow on Contact AfterInsert and AfterUpdate before the `ACCT_IndividualAccounts_TDTM`?  Or else, should I insert a new hierarchical setting for the NPSP Household Setting that applies to my Devlopment team wherein I enable it?  Is there another way?

(As an aside, how can the `ACCT_IndividualAccounts_TDTM` run BeforeUpdate/Insert?)

Comment: Do you have access to the Hub? The NPSP developers are pretty active over there.

Comment: @MikeChale I do.  That's a good idea, but I've had some good insights from this community as well, so I'm interested answers might come from here, too.